# CASE WHEN with COUNTIF in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need a sum(case when..) in the following scenario and would like to convert the IF(COUNTIF()) to SQL, but am confused how that it remains in the case as I would like to keep it in 1 column.

```
CASE WHEN Column1 IN ('Apples', 'Bananas') THEN Column1
     WHEN Column2 = 'False' THEN 'FALSE IT IS'
     IF(COUNTIF(A1:A3;'Yes')>1) THEN 'Yes'    -- EXCEL (how to convert this to SQL)
ELSE 'No'
END
```

Comment: `A1:A3` is a range. How do you envision that translating to SQL? Are those cells represented by three columns? You'll just have to spell them out then: `WHEN (IIF(Column1 = 'Yes', 1, 0) + IIF(Column2 = 'Yes', 1, 0) + ...) > 1 THEN 'Yes'`.

Comment: On the other hand, if `A1:A3` is to be translated to SQL as ranging over *rows*, the solution is completely different (and far more complicated). But in that case you'll have to be clearer on what you input set and desired result look like.

Comment: Your first answer is on the spot Jeroen, thank you!